# Upgrading existing Windows 7 Pro licenses to Ent?

Tags: windows, windows-7, licensing

From our license info page from MS:

Agreement Info: MOLP-Z Std
...
License Date: 2011-03-02
Microsoft Invoice No: 91....
Reorder/Upgrade End Date: *2013-03-31*

MS Win Pro 7 Sngl Open 1 License  Part no: FQC-02872 Qty: 120
MS Win Server CAL 2008 Sng Open 1 Part no: R18-02709 Qty: 120

Now we want to upgrade to Enteprise but the reseller says "Sorry, you need to buy *new* licenses, 120x Win7Pro (FQC-02872) and 120x SoftwareAssurance (FQC-02368).

Are they trying to rip us off?? "Upgrade End Date" still not here and why do we need to re-order exactly same part number (FQC-02872) only 1 year later?

Comment: What is the difference between pro and enterprise?

Comment: @Luke, things like Bitlocker whole drive encryption

Comment: Ultimate has whole drive encryption.....As others point you cannot upgrade from any comsumer level product to enterprise.  If you want enterprise in theory you could forfit your Professional licenses and perhaps pay the difference.  You really should just talk to MICROSOFT about this.  WE CANNOT HELP YOU.

Comment: @Ramhound, who said we have consumer level product? FQC-02872 as described in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt they are trying to rip you off, [Professional can only be upgraded to Ultimate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#sectionSection1) (you can not go from Ultimate to Enterprise either, but why would you want to?). But you will need to ask them about using the same product code.

The enterprise paths and the retail paths do not cross each other in Windows 7.

```
From Windows 7     Anytime Upgrade to Windows 7

Home Basic         Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate

Home Premium       Professional, Ultimate

Professional       Ultimate

Starter            Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate
```

If you had Vista Business you could go from Business to Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate but once you are on 7 you are stuck on whatever branch you started on.

```
From Windows Vista (SP1, SP2)  Upgrade to Windows 7

Business                       Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate

Enterprise                     Enterprise

Home Basic                     Home Basic, Home Premium, Ultimate

Home Premium                   Home Premium, Ultimate

Ultimate                       Ultimate
```

---

**UPDATE**: After checking the internet and seeing a [strangely familiar](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/win7pro-fqc-02872-is-upgradeable-to-win7ent/55d27f98-495d-41d4-a033-0d8466431565) question on another site, You can not do a in-place upgrade from pro->ent however it does qualify if you want to get the cheaper upgrade licenses than buying them new. But it will require a re-install of windows.

Comment: I always thought of Pro as part of the Enterprise path, (because of domain joining, I guess), but I guess I was wrong there.