# Is it possible to upgrade windows 7 Pro (Volume License) to Enterprise without rebuilding

Tags: windows-7

is it possible to upgrade windows 7 pro (volume license) to enterprise without rebuilding the whole pc.

i would use anytime upgrade but it's not available on the volume license edition.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of: https://serverfault.com/questions/420903/upgrading-existing-windows-7-pro-licenses-to-ent  -- this question asks if the PC can be upgraded "without rebuilding the whole pc" -- it's not a licensing question.

Answer (score 6):

I honestly don't know if it still works with all of the patches MS put out over the last few years for Windows 7, but you used to be able to trick it via the registry and then do an in-place upgrade.

To try this on a single computer first (one you really don't care about):

1. Open `regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version` then change to “Enterprise” in ProductName and EditionID
3. Start the ISO/DVD of Win 7 Enterprise within Windows and do an in-place upgrade

After the upgrade (assuming it still works this way) reboot and then change the product key to the Enterprise key.

Comment: This does appear to still work.

Comment: Still works as of today!

Comment: I also just verified this to still work. However, the language of the Windows 7 Enterprise DVD/ISO needs to be the same as the already-existent Pro installation, otherwise the Installer refuses to do the upgrade.

Comment: I also confirm that this still works, as of today.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. They're completely different in Microsoft world. They are not part of the same licensing path.

Comment: what about to ultimate?

Comment: Yes, you can use Anytime for Pro->Ultimate.